# Opening and closing times with 24 hour clock

Tags: ios, clock, nscalendar

I am developing an application in which I need to ensure a service is open (i.e. the current hour lies within the service's opening hours).

I am using a 24 hour clock and am having difficulty writing the logic to get it working correctly, mainly due to the overnight (0-12) hours. My current solution is the following but as I mentioned it doesn't work because if the closing hour is 5 (5am) and the current hour is 22 (10pm), 22>5 = true, so it returns false and fails.

My question is thus how do I handle 0-12am hours effectively?

```
if (self.hour < start || self.hour >= end)
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
// get current hour
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let now = NSDate()
let dateComponents = calendar.components(.Hour, fromDate: now)
let currentHour = dateComponents.hour

// opening hours
let startingHour = 22
let endingHour = 6

// check for different starting and ending hour
if startingHour == endingHour {
    print("no valid opening hours")
    // return
}

// check if current hour is within opening hours
if startingHour < endingHour {
    // e.g. 7 - 15
    if currentHour >= startingHour && currentHour < endingHour {
        print("opened")
    } else {
        print("closed")
    }
} else {
    // e.g. 22 - 6
    if currentHour >= startingHour || currentHour < endingHour {
        print("opened")
    } else {
        print("closed")
    }
}
```